# Is this use of the phrase "of which" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

The sentence is:

"Looking at the manual with the mindset of a penetration tester, of which I am, one can see that..."

Is this sentence perfectly sound, grammatically? If not, why not?

Comment: That should be *of which I am **one*** - but it might look a bit odd in your exact context, since the following clause starts with ***one*** as well. So maybe either rephrase the parenthetical "of which I am one", or switch your existing ***one*** to ***we*** or ***you*** (which doesn't really affect anything, since they're all just general-purpose pronouns effectively referencing ***anybody, a person, no-one in particular***).

Comment: (But I don't think it's idiomatic to have ***of which I am one*** referencing the singular noun phrase ***a penetration tester***, and things start to get a bit messy if we try to pluralise *that* in the specific context. In short, there are problems with idiomacy here as well as basic syntax/grammar.)

Comment: Strictly speaking, since you say "with the mindset of a penetration tester" the word 'which' relates to the _mindset_ not to the _occupation_. This means that it could be argued that you should say "which I have" rather than "of which I am one". But that's probably being painfully pedantic.

Comment: As a tech writer, I'd edit the entire thing to something like "If you look at the manual with the mindset of a penetration tester, you can see that..." Whether the author is a tester or not is probably irrelevant, depending on context. If not irrelevant in context, then that info should be presented earlier in the text, possibly in an "About the Author" intro.